# How to capture and manage the minutes of meeting for the team?

Tags: meetings

Usually in many meetings some designated person note down various points/minutes and send that note as an email to all participants.

However, overtime i find that emails become too much of a pile of information. It becomes difficult to track the meetings and specially followup the meetings on the same subject.

What are some best tools and practices for collecting and managing minutes of meeting? How do you organize it and make it accessible to the team (and yourself) for future reference?

Comment: Not sure of the close votes, I think information and strategies on capturing meeting minutes are important and don't come naturally.

Comment: I agree, but I think the way this is phrased is not constructive. We generally don't do well with `What is the best...?` kinds of questions in the SE Q&A format. Plus, this is private beta. The key question to ask with every question is: would I want to show someone this site with this question as a potential first-landing page?

Comment: Aarthi is correct, at the moment this question is easily interpreted as simply asking for a list of suggestions -- [**Great subjective questions tend to have long, not short, answers**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Please feel free to edit so that it encourages longer, detailed answers and flag for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

My company uses [Microsoft OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/). It does a decent job and is easy to collaborate with so you can have people confirm what they said and correct the notes as needed after the meeting.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't OneNote also support a shared notebook with multiple people editing at the same time? I don't use a laptop at work, so I can't be confirm, but I've heard of people doing that.

Comment: Yes it can. In a lot of meetings we have the a shared One-note notebook up on the projector with one person taking notes so everyone can see what they are writing. Anyone else in the meeting can either correct the notes on the fly or edit them on their own as needed in real time.

Answer (score 0):

A recording of the meeting using tools like [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) and a simple log/to-do list should be enough. Keep meetings as simple and short as possible.